# Ionic 2 - Storage always empty until reloading the app

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, ionic2

I am currently building an application with Ionic 2 and using the Storage plugin to hold my values which are pretty much just an API Token and user profile since the application pulls all data from an API.

I am testing the application via `ionic serve` because no native functions are used but now I am facing the problem that every time I store a value in the Storage the value is not accessible until I reload the app which is kind of annoying because after the user logs in he gets redirected to a page that requires the API token which is not available until I reload the app so the whole thing gets stuck in a loop.

Ionic Storage is using IndexedDB in the browser where I can see that the values have been stored when I check them with Chrome Developer tools.

I have been trying to figure out the issue but can't find any reason why the storage values are not available until reloading the app.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpClientService } from './http-client-service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(public events: Events, public storage: Storage, public http: HttpClientService) {
        //
    }

    login(user) {
        var response = this.http.post('login', {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
        });

        response.subscribe(data => {
            this.storage.set('api_token', data.token);

            console.log('raw : ' + data.token); // shows the api token

            this.storage.get('api_token').then((value) => {
                console.log('storage : '+ value); // is empty...
            });
        });

        return response;
    };
}
```

**Edit: I managed to track down the issue to the storage running async which results in the token not being added to the headers.**

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    // this does add the header in time
    localStorage.setItem('api_token', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vYXBpLndpaHplLmRldi9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ4MTE4MzQyOCwiZXhwIjoxNDgxMTg3MDI4LCJuYmYiOjE0ODExODM0MjgsImp0aSI6IjdlNTE1WUEwWmE4NWc2QjUiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6MX19.T4KpqgCB8xU79vKyeLG4CJ0OHLpVI0j37JKIBJ_0CC4');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('api_token'));

    // this does not add the header in time
    return this.storage.get('api_token').then((value) => {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + value);
    });
}

getHeaders(path) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    if(!this.isGuestRoute(path)) {
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    }

    return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
}

get(path: string) {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + path, this.getHeaders(path))
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, doesn't `this.storage.set` return a `Promise`? Or am I confusing it with a different storage?

Comment: Would at least explain the fact that it *is* there when you reload, async stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, looked in the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/) and I do understand why you put them both underneath eachother since they also display it like that in the docs.

But `Storage.set(key, value)` :

> Returns:
>   Promise that resolves when the value is set

This means that you cannot use it the way you are using it (hence why they added a comment with `//or ....`

Since resolving a Promise is asynchronous.

If you want to use the value like you're currently using it (which seems a bit odd but probably for you to test if the value is set correctly) you should use

```
this.storage.set('api_token', data.token).then(() => {
   this.storage.get('api_token').then((value) => {
       console.log('storage : '+ value); // is empty...
    });
});

console.log('raw : ' + data.token); // shows the api token
```

If you would like some more information about why this happens, check out this SO answer (I prefer second one) [Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but still does not explain why the value is only available after reloading the app. I tested if the value is available with an event that I fired in the `storage.set` promise and the event simply called the `storage.get` and the value was available but when I navigate to the account page right after the login everything fails because the API Token is not available, if I refresh the app and then navigate to the account page everything is working fine.

So am I still missing something or why is the value not populated throughout the whole application?

Comment: Do you push to the account page within the `storage.set().then()`? Because else the problem might again be the async execution.

Comment: No, I send the user to the HomePage and then I manually navigate to the AccountPage where I call `this.userService.me()` which just sends an HTTP GET Request which at the moment fails if I don't reload the app because the API Token is not available no matter how long I wait. I navigate manually there to test if the data get properly loaded.

Comment: hmm weird, sounds more like a problem from the Storage, or an error in you `userService.me()`

Comment: Well the `me` method simply returns `return this.http.get('http://api.com/users/me', bodyAndAuthHeader);` to which I subscribe and assign the data to the AccountPage user variable so nothing fancy happening there. The `Authorization` header of my request is always empty until I reload the app and then magically the `api_token` value is available. The `api_token` value is not available anywhere in the application until I reload it.

Comment: I have added some more code so it is apparent what I am trying to do